# Create CHECK constraint SQL

Tags: sql, constraints

I hope you can help me.

I would like to create a check constraint that ensure the column `INKOOPBEDRAG` has to be higher than `PRIJS_PER_D`.

In the table `INKOOPOVEREENKOMST.[BARCODE]` it is a FK to `ARTIKEL.[BARCODE]`.

I have created the following `CHECK` constraint, but I get an error:

```
CHECK CK_inkoopbedraghogerdprijs CHECK (INKOOPOVEREENKOMST.[INKOOPBEDRAG] > [artikel][d_prijs])
```

[image]

Comment: Check constraints can only access values of the row checked, not other rows of the same, let alone another table. You'd have to write triggers on both tables. Or maybe change your design.

Comment: @stickybit is there another sort of constraint that I can create to solve this problem. Changing the design is not possible

Comment: As I said, you can write triggers on both tables that check, if a change of values violates your rules and throw an error if so.

Comment: @stickybit how would that look on my request I never worked with triggers before as I am fairly new to SQL

Comment: The syntax would have to be `CONSTRAINT (name) CHECK (check condition)` - but as @stickybit already mentioned - `CHECK` constraints cannot compare to other tables than the current one

Comment: @marc_s I have worked with `check` but I have not worked with `trigger` and dont know how to write them

Comment: Re "I have not worked with trigger and dont know how to write them" - usually there exists some documentation for particular flavour of sql server. Here on SO no one will write code for you, also no one will create tutorials - there are much better teaching and informational resources available.

Comment: @Mafklaper A trigger is code that is "triggered" by certain actions (I.e. an update or an insert), and can execute prior to or after the action. In your case, you could implement it as a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on the `Inkoopovereenkomst` table, and prevent data from being inserted if the `[INKOOPOVEREENKOMST].[INKOOPBEDRAG]` > `[artikel].[d_prijs]`. 

Please keep in mind that Triggers are not the most obvious code (Mostly due to how they are listed in Management Studio). Also, triggers will typically fire on a per-row basis, and thus can cause performance issue.

Comment: @SchmitzIT: They additionally need triggers on `artikel` as a change of `d_prijs` can also lead to a violation of the rule. Also just covering `INSERT`s on `inkoopovereenkomst` isn't enough. `UPDATE`s must be checked here too.

Comment: @SchmitzIT so the code would be the following
`CREATE TRIGGER inkoopbedragdagprijs
BEFORE INSERT
BEGIN
CHECK inkoopovereenkomts.[inkoopprijs] > artikel.[d_prijs}
END`

Comment: @stickybit True. I didn't consider changes in Artikel. And due to max length of comments, I deliberately kept things short. I mostly wanted to provide some basic pointers as to what to google for.

Comment: @Mafklaper - Try having a look at Example C on the Trigger documentation page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

In short, no, you do not use the `CHECK` keyword at all. Note what @stickybit added to ensure you properly take updates on Artikel into account. And be very sure to avoid 2 triggers creating updates that end up firing one another.

Comment: @SchmitzIT: The triggers shouldn't `UPDATE` anything, just check, so they won't fire each other anyway. But well, I hope the OP got the idea to think it thoroughly through and take `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s on both tables into account, as all of them might cause a violation of the rule. It isn't such a simple task if one wants to do it right. That's the actual point.

Comment: @stickybit True. In OPs case, it sounds like just the warning would suffice. In my mind I was thinking of a situation where there'd be an automatic update to include a 25% profit margin or something like that. I figured it would be worth at least adding a warning. I have seen developers build triggers that fired other triggers, and it can very quickly escalate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the following:

```
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnCHK_InkoophogerAlsDPrijs
(@barcode INT, @INKOOPBEDRAG SMALLMONEY)
RETURNS BIT --1 or 0
AS
   BEGIN
   RETURN CASE WHEN EXISTS(
   SELECT *
   FROM Artikel
   WHERE barcode = @barcode
   AND [Prijs_per_d] < @INKOOPBEDRAG)
   THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END
END;
GO
```

Then I added a `Constraint` as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE [Inkoopovereenkomst] ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_InkoophogerAlsDPrijs CHECK (dbo.fnCHK_InkoophogerAlsDPrijs(Barcode, Inkoopbedrag) = 1);
```